# how to change width of objects in array with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some element in my html code like following:

```
<DIV id="slideshow-container">
    <DIV id="slideshow">
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Now i will get li elements and set width of that with jquery. But my code not work.
The following is my code:

```
var slides = $('#slideshow li');
var w=$('#slideshow').width();

for(var j=0;j<slides.length;j++){
    slides.get(j).css('width',w);
}
```

Do you know where is my mistake?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this...

```
slides.css('width', w);
```

... should be sufficient. As `.css` is used as a setter, quoting [**the doc**](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> ...set one or more CSS properties for **every matched element**.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aNDWS/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd change:

```
for(var j=0;j<slides.length;j++){
    slides.get(j).css('width',w);
}
```

to:

```
$('#slideshow li').each(function(){
    $(this).width(w);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 slides.eq(j).css('width',w);
```

To

```
 slides.eq(j).css('width',w+'px');
```

`x.width() return 80`

While in `css` it should be with `unit` :

```
x.css('width','80px')
```

Answer (score 0):

`slides.get(j)` returns the DOM object for each `<li>`, rather than the jQuery object.

This should work:

```
$( slides.get(j) ).css('width',w);
```

Or, instead of the `for` loop:

```
slides.each(function () {
    $(this).css('width', w);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an array of those elements, but you actually have to change them on the view, use an `each` and modify `this`

```
var w=$('#slideshow').width();
$("#slideshow ul li").each(function() {
    $(this).css("width", w);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
for(var j=0;j<slides.length;j++){
    slides.get(j).css('width',w);
}
```

with

```
slides.each(function () {
    $(this).css('width', w + 'px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## jQuery Solution (slower, easier to implement)

If jQuery is required for other things in your site, and speed is not really a concern to you, here's the jQuery way to achieve the same result:

```
$("#slideshow li").width(w);
```

## Non-jQuery solution (faster)

jQuery is *significantly* slower than simple javascript dom manipulation.

### Create a simple library for javascript you need - reuse is good.

jQuery is a very large library for doing something so straightforward.
*Note: Example uses namespacing.  Encapsulation is better, but namespacing is a good start.*

```
var myNS = {
    elById: document.getElementById,
    elsByParentId: function (id, optionalTagName) {
        var tag = optionalTagName || "*";
        return myNS.elByID(id).getElementsByTagName(tag);
    }
    setWidthForEls: function (els, w) {
        for (var i=0, c=els.length; i < c; i++){
        els[i].style.width = w;
    },
    getWidthOfEl: function (el){
        return el.style.width;
    }
    setWidthForElsFromEl: function (els, el) {
        myNS.setWidthForEls(els, myNS.getWidthOfEl(el));
    }
}
```

#### Then, in the code section you are referring to, you just do:

```
myNS.setWidthForElsFromEl(
    myNS.elsByParentID("slideshow","li"),
    myN.elByID("content")
);
```